# Force a Mac app to open in a specific desktop space

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a music player application and I want it to be permanently opened as a Dock or like a widget in a particular corner of my desktop space, with a play and pause button with song title. What is the right approach?

Comment: Desktop space of a Mac using iOS?  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

To make it stay on top you would have to do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {            
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
}
```

You can move the window by adjusting its frame, should be easy enough to figure yourself.

Comment: I actually set the app to top using  IBinterface  will your code help me to keep the app at top, i.e. even when I opened another app this music player controls should be still in the foremost layer so that I can pause and play song even while I am browsing in safari. I don't want to minimise browser to pause that is what I am aiming for.. I am new to OS X programming..